# ¿Como debería ser el código o la redireccion 301?

Tags: .htaccess

Acabamos de cambiar de version de la plataforma de Joomla 2.5 to Joomla 3.8. El problema es que ya tenía muchas URLs indexadas con esta estructura:

http://www.garden.es/index.php/noticias-actualidad/2840-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Y las nuevas que acabamos de fijar son sin el número que representa el ID

http://www.garden.es/index.php/noticias-actualidad/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Me esta produciendo muchos errores 404, no se si con 301 podría arreglarlos pero claro no puedo ir una por una. Existe algún código que pudiera quitar ese valor de todas las URLs, ya que solamente sin el número serían validas

Comment: traduce tu pregunta, estas en la versión en español de SO, de otro modo terminará cerrada

Answer (score 0):

Hola podrías agregar una regla en tu archivo .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/2840-(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/$2 [NC,R=302,L]
```

El estado 301 significa que el recurso (página) se mueve permanentemente a una nueva ubicación.

Espero haberte apoyado.
Saludos

### Info adicional:

El estado 301 significa que el recurso (página) se mueve permanentemente a una nueva ubicación. El cliente / navegador no debe intentar solicitar la ubicación original, sino usar la nueva ubicación de ahora en adelante.

El estado 302 significa que el recurso se encuentra temporalmente en otro lugar, y el cliente / navegador debe continuar solicitando la URL original.

Comment: Perdóname pero el valor que puse es de una URL ejemplo, necesitaría ver como es con muchas URLs y valores distintos. Sería quitar los números que aparezcan tras la barra y el guión medio. Por supuesto que me ayudas. Mil gracia

Comment: Si lo aplicas en tu archivo .htaccess, eso se aplica a todas las URL de tu dominio. esto elimina los números y el guion medio.

Comment: Si pero en este caso solo me quitaría el 2840, que es el id el ejemplo. Como puedo hacer para que quite todo ID que podrían medir 1,2,3,4 caracteres.